# Insert data into MySQL database using batch

Tags: batch-file, cmd, variable-assignment, windows-console

I'm encountering difficulties when trying to insert data into my `MySQL` database using a batch script. Here's the script I'm currently using:

```
set query=INSERT INTO `my_tbl` (`age` ,`birthdate`) VALUES (15, NOW());
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root  --password=SECRET -e "%query%" my_db
```

However, when I execute the script, I receive the following error message: `VALUES was unexpected.`

In addition to resolving the error, I would like to replace the static value of `15` with a variable.

The `birthdate` column is of `timestamp` data type, while the `age` column is of `integer` data type.

Answer (score 0):

I added a variable called age and set it to 15 then i use it after values keyword. I hope it works.

```bash
set age=15
set query=INSERT INTO `my_tbl` (`age`, `birthdate`) VALUES (%age%, NOW())

C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root --password=SECRET -e "%query%" my_db
```

Or if you want to align the command simply type

```bash
C:\wamp64\bin\mysql\mysql5.7.36\bin\mysql.exe -h localhost --user=root --password=SECRET -e "SET @age=15; INSERT INTO my_tbl (age, birthdate) VALUES (@age, NOW());" my_db
```